How to hide an authentication token on Nuxt.js 2?
I needed to query my Strapi backend from my NuxtJS frontend via Apollo, using a JWT authentication token.
I searched a lot, without success, on how to hide the authentication token on Nuxt.js 2. I tried with .env and privateRuntimeConfig :

With .env, when I was using process.env.MY_KEY, the value of the key was displayed in plain text in /_nuxt/app.js, in the browser.
With privateRuntimeConfig, I simply couldn't access to the key from the nuxt.config.js.

Here is my nuxt.config.js Apollo configuration :


apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
            ? process.env.BACKEND_URL ||
              "my-website.com/graphql"
            : process.env.BACKEND_URL || "http://localhost:1337/graphql",

        httpLinkOptions: {
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer MY_JWT_TOKEN`,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },



Feel free to ask for additional informations.

I explained it several times with different approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+private Overall, need a middleware backend of some sort: Nuxt itself, cloud function, regular backend server or something alike. A frontend meta-framework cannot do any magic. Using Nuxt 3 (with Nitro) will also make things far more easier.

Another thing to know is that some tokens are supposed to be public and, hence can be exposed on the client side. While some tokens are meant to be secret and used on a "backend solution".

I couldn't really find a solution that fit my problem... Still, I think that my token shouldn't be visible, because it allows to create entries in Strapi. I spend a lot of time on it, but I am sorry if my question is a bit stupid. I think that I am misunderstanding or missing something. Thank you so much.

Nah the question is not stupid or anything. It's more that for the given use-case, you need to go outside of Nuxt depending on how you would like to do things. If you are sure that you need to hide it, you should use a middleware solution to hide it on some backend, as said in my first comment.

But I am not sure to understand the way to set up the middleware in my context. How I tried, it was giving the same result as .env

Oh, it's you again (I remember helping you on your website). Overall, here you need to ditch the .env approach because it is not the way. You need to handle an external request to some kind of backend to obfuscate the secret token and come back with the processed answer. This is still the easiest way to hide something private.

Yes, it's me :). But as long as I import the config or the middleware in the nuxt.config.js, the token will be visible.

Exactly, hence why I am telling you to not import it there but to use an external backend to do the transaction.

But what I don't understand, is how to configure Apollo for the whole nuxt app outside of nuxt?

You will need to configure it based on the fact that there is an in-between service. There is maybe an option for it (having a proxy server), otherwise, you'll need to make it yourself. The fact that it's GraphQL or REST doesn't make any difference IMO.

I just ended with migrating this project to Nuxt 3 and started to use @nuxtjs/strapi instead of Apollo. What do you advice @kissu to add and hide a auth header?

Nuxt3 is a very good choice yes, as for Apollo it was probably not necessary indeed. Tbh, use your app as SSG so that you don't need to worry about anything once your app is generated (no need to worry about hiding things if everything is generated at build time).

@kissu Finally, to add the auth header properly, I ended with going back to Apollo for Nuxt 3. So, I still have the same issue : wether I am using SSG or SSR, the token is visible, because frontend will still request backend to display the data.

Why not go full static and build it once without making external calls? Do you even need to make external calls after building your app with the content from the CMS? I still don't think that Apollo is anyhow useful for your use-case tho.

Even if I don't use Apollo, I need to make calls to the backend to get the data. So it would be the same with any tool (@nuxtjs/strapi, nuxt-graphql-request, nuxt-graphql-client...). Same also with any rendering mode.

Did you gave a read to full static mode? https://nuxt.com/blog/going-full-static Basically if you don't do any runtime calls once coming to your app, you might consider building everything on build time. Do you make any sensitive calls on runtime? What's the data you're getting?

By full static mode, you mean SPA ? No, the data is for a blog. But I don't want anyone to be able to access to the authenticated API, because if it is the case, anyone will be able to create entries on my blog!

Full static is the opposite of SPA. Please give it a read. If I propose such a solution it's because it might help you hide your stuff. I mean, I am making assumptions because you haven't told me if your calls are runtime or build time. But I think it's a safe assumption for a blog.

I pretty sure my calls are runtime. Full static is SSG? I couldn’t build my app this way because all the pages were returning 500 errors of pre-rendering.

Could you please illustrate what the calls are exactly? I doubt they are runtime-only, and could rather be build-time. Full static is indeed SSG. Not sure what you did but they are not supposed to do that. Guess the easiest way is still to make a call to discuss that one because I'll take too much time to explain all the things here. Send me an email again: hello@kissu.io

Thank you so much for your help and your time. Do you advise to use axios more than Apollo to do the calls? Maybe it would be easier to handle build time / server side calls? I will write you tomorrow morning!

I advise you to use the built-in $fetch of Nuxt3 for any of your calls. It doesn't make any call simpler, that's unrelated.

OP solved the issue by using a Strapi token that is read-only, preventing any undesired person from being able to edit OP's CMS content.
Other alternatives would have been:

using any cloud functions, like the ones on Netlify
using another server somewhere as a proxy
using Nuxt3's innate server capabilities
keeping the content server-side only by using Nuxt server components

